# Node SSDP Client not finding Server broadcast

Tags: node.js, sockets, networking, udp, ssdp

I've implemented a server/client implementation of `node-ssdp`(`npm install node-ssdp`). Everything "appears" to work but my client does not pick up the server's packet. I am receiving a lot of other payloads from different devices/locations but not the payload from my `node-ssdp` server.

I'm running on the same machine and I'm running on OSX. I have two separate node projects: one for my client and one for my server.

**Note**: I've also tried running the server on one machine and the client on a separate machine, in case there was an issue with loopback or something. I also verified via Wireshark that the packets from the server were being read by the client machine. It is sending a `NOTIFY * HTTP/1.1` in the headers.

Here are my implementations for client and server:

**Server**

```
var SSDP = require('node-ssdp').Server
, server = new SSDP({
location: 'http://' + require('ip').address() + ':33333',
ssdpPort: 33333
})
console.log(require('ip').address())
server.addUSN('upnp:rootdevice')
server.addUSN('urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:MediaServer:1')
server.addUSN('urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ContentDirectory:1')
server.addUSN('urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ConnectionManager:1')

server.on('advertise-alive', function (heads) {
  console.log('advertise-alive', heads)
  // Expire old devices from your cache.
  // Register advertising device somewhere (as designated in http headers heads)
})

server.on('advertise-bye', function (heads) {
  console.log('advertise-bye', heads)
  // Remove specified device from cache.
})

// start server on all interfaces
console.log('starting ssdp server')
server.start()
```

**Client**

```
var ssdp = require('node-ssdp').Client
  , client = new ssdp({
})

client.on('notify', function () {
  //console.log('Got a notification.')
})

client.on('response', function inResponse(headers, code, rinfo) {
  console.log('Got a response to an m-search:\n%d\n%s\n%s', code, JSON.stringify(headers, null, '  '), JSON.stringify(rinfo, null, '  '))
})

client.search('ssdp:all')

// And after 10 seconds, you want to stop
setTimeout(function () {
   client.stop()
}, 10000)
```

I am running out of ideas. It's weird because I've previously implemented a UDP multicast solution and it works. SSDP is, from what I understand, UDP multicast behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

From the github issue itself, apparently adding `sourcePort` to the configuration solved the issue. https://github.com/diversario/node-ssdp/issues/75#issuecomment-292054892